# Why is VNC broken in 14.04 Desktop and how do I fix it?

Tags: vnc

I don't consider myself to be an idiot, but clearly I am. So please help the idiot.
I have a brand new clean install of Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS running on vmware. I wishto access it from a Windows 7 computer. Sounds easy enough So I went to a Terminal and ran vncserver which required me to set a password and then appeared to be running.

I then installed UltraVNC on my Windows 7 computer (Viewer only) and then tried to connect. After entering the password (which confirms to me I am reaching the computer) all I get is a blank screen. After much Googling this seems to be the normal response. I have studied many google articles most of which involve magical incantations of one form or another, but nothing I can do will make it work.

The vncserver log file complains "error opening security policy file /etc/X11/xserver/SecurityPolicy" followed by a bunch of messsages "Could not init font path element...."

After that it shows what appears to be valid connections or disconnections, but I can never get any thing to display on the screen. Surely this should just work right out of the box.

I decided to add to this post from the Ubuntu computer so I can add so I can add the log and xstartup file using cut and paste.

```
     Sun Feb 22 17:42:13 2015
      vncext:      VNC extension running!
      vncext:      Listening for VNC connections on port 5901
      vncext:      created VNC server for screen 0
     error opening security policy file /etc/X11/xserver/SecurityPolicy
     Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/Type1/, removing from list!
     Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/Speedo/, removing from list!
     Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/misc/, removing from list!
     Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/75dpi/, removing from list!
     Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/100dpi/, removing from list!
     Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/, removing from list!
     Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/, removing from list!

     Sun Feb 22 17:42:42 2015
      Connections: accepted: 0.0.0.0::54270
      SConnection: Client needs protocol version 3.8
      SConnection: Client requests security type VncAuth(2)

     Sun Feb 22 17:42:49 2015
      SConnection: AuthFailureException: Authentication failure
      Connections: closed: 0.0.0.0::54270 (Authentication failure)

     Sun Feb 22 17:43:21 2015
      Connections: accepted: 0.0.0.0::54281
      SConnection: Client needs protocol version 3.8
      SConnection: Client requests security type VncAuth(2)

     Sun Feb 22 17:43:28 2015
      VNCSConnST:  Server default pixel format depth 16 (16bpp) little-endian rgb565
      VNCSConnST:  Client pixel format depth 16 (16bpp) little-endian rgb565

     Sun Feb 22 17:43:41 2015
      Connections: closed: 0.0.0.0::54281 (Clean disconnection)
      SMsgWriter:  framebuffer updates 3
      SMsgWriter:    ZRLE rects 4, bytes 1380
      SMsgWriter:    raw bytes equivalent 3146800, compression ratio 2280.289855

     #!/bin/sh

     # Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
     unset SESSION_MANAGER
     exec sh /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc

     [ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] &amp;&amp; exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
     [ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] &amp;&amp; xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
     #xsetroot -solid grey
     #vncconfig -iconic &
     #x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
     startx &amp;
```

Comment: What are you expecting to see? if you want to see/interact with the logged-in session on the Ubuntu Desktop, you should enable the default vino-server (via 'Desktop Sharing') rather than using vncserver (which starts a separate, standalone X session). You may need to play with vino-server's `require-encryption` setting to get it to play nice with UltraVNC.

Comment: I stopped the vncserver and opened Desktop Sharing checked some boxes and clicked OK. It gives no indication that it is running. But then what do I do? I tried using UltraVNC again but it fails to connect. It doesn't even ask for a password

Comment: Is there an error message?  if so, what is it? what port/display are you trying to connect to?

Comment: "Failed to connect to server" The IP address is correct and the port is 5901. It's like there is no VNC service running.

Comment: The vino-server will run on port 5900 (corresponding to display :0) by default. Whereas a standalone VNC instance such as vncserver will have selected the next available port/display - which is why it defaults to 5901/:1

Comment: I tried connecting to port 5900 - same result

Comment: You will *probably* need to disable the `require-encryption` setting on vino-server as well: `gsettings set org.gnome.Vino require-encryption 'false'`

Comment: That did it - MANY thanks - why on earth isn't that explained anywhere in all the articles about this?

Comment: It's a newish "feature" of the default vino-server config, I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With help from steeldriver the solution is mind-blowingly simple. Forget about vncserver and instead search for "Desktop Sharing". Answer the questions and then use VNC to connect to port 5900 or :0. 
It might be necessary, depending on your client to disable encryption. This can be done from a terminal using:

```
    gsettings set org.gnome.Vino require-encryption 'false'
```

Comment: Just be aware that VNC is **not** a secure protocol, so if your Ubuntu machine is exposed to the public internet (even briefly) it may be compromised by having open VNC ports: you should consider fire-walling the vino-server and/or having it only listen on the `lo` interface, and connecting only via an SSH tunnel.

Comment: It's on my internal network and only accessible from my Windows PC